# How to use single where and multiple or in brackets in laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to write this sql in laravel elequent.

```
      select * from user where status = 1 and (name = 'jones' or email = 'demo@gmail')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation. Your query is pretty much the same as the example given in it https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping

Comment: @IGP I have read that but I want to use eloquent not query builder.

Comment: Eloquent is the same as the query builder. `User::where(...)` is the same as `DB::table('users')->where(...)` in terms of the query and syntax used. It says so right in the first paragraph of the documentation for retrieving eloquent models. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use eloquent like this

```
User::where('status',1)->where('name','jones')->orWhere('email','demo@gmail')->get();
```